# Problema com autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer um input com auto complete por consulta no banco mysql, porém estou tendo problemas. Fiz todo o código seguindo um tutorial e mesmo assim não vai, nem erros me aparece. Quando digito não aparecem opções para completar. Segue o código:

pg index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Auto Complete</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form action="t" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">


    <label>Cliente:</label>

    <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto">
 </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#assunto").autocomplete({
                source: 'retornaCliente.php' 
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

pg retornCliente

```
<?php 

include 'conexao.php';
$pdo = conectar();

$assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NOME_LOJA FROM lojas WHERE NOME_LOJA LIKE '%".$assunto."%' ORDER BY NOME_LOJA ASC ");
$buscar->execute();

    while ($result = $buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dados[] = $result['NOME_LOJA'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dados);

$assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//SQL para selecionar os registros
$result_msg_cont = "SELECT assunto FROM mensagens_contatos WHERE assunto LIKE '%".$assunto."%' ORDER BY assunto ASC LIMIT 7";

//Seleciona os registros
$resultado_msg_cont = $conn->prepare($result_msg_cont);
$resultado_msg_cont->execute();

while($row_msg_cont = $resultado_msg_cont->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = $row_msg_cont['assunto'];
}

echo json_encode($data)

 ?>
```

a conexão com o banco está ok pois testei separado, se aguém poder me ajudo agradeço.

Comment: a sua string de conexão é  $pdo ou $conn?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, não deixe de marcar uma resposta como aceita se a mesma resolver seu problema. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Você está retornando 2 json separados, esse é um dos problemas. Junte tudo num array só, e depois gere o JSON. Pra testar, é bom acessar o recurso diretamente sem AJAX, e ver se o resultado é o que vc espera. Além disso, deve olhar o log de erros do PHP pra ver problemas adicionais. Tem outros probleminhas como estar recuperando desnecessariamente o assunto duas vezes, e um problema de injeção de SQL, além de uma mistura de variáveis de conexão diferentes, e falta de tratamento de erros. Seria melhor não acumular tantos probleminhas assim de uma vez para não atrasar o desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Você está retornando 2 json separados, esse é um dos problemas. Junte tudo num array só `$data[]`, e depois gere o JSON. Pra testar, é bom acessar o recurso diretamente sem AJAX, e ver se o resultado é o que vc espera. Além disso, deve olhar o log de erros do PHP pra ver problemas adicionais. Tem outros problemas como de injeção de SQL, além de uma mistura de variáveis de conexão diferentes, e falta de tratamento de erros. Seria melhor não acumular tantos probleminhas assim de uma vez para não atrasar o desenvolvimento. (by Bacco).

**Dito isso, ou melhor, importado isso, Mãos à Obra!**

**retornaCliente.php**

```
<?php 

        $hostname="localhost";  
        $username="USUARIO";  
        $password="SENHA";  
        $db = "Nome_DB";  
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

    $assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $buscar = $pdo->prepare('SELECT NOME_LOJA FROM lojas WHERE NOME_LOJA LIKE ? ORDER BY NOME_LOJA ASC');
    $buscar->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

    while ($results = $buscar->fetch())
    {
        $data[] = $results['NOME_LOJA'];
    }


    //SQL para selecionar os registros
    $result_msg_cont = $pdo->prepare('SELECT assunto FROM mensagens_contatos WHERE assunto LIKE ? ORDER BY assunto ASC LIMIT 7');
    $result_msg_cont->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

    while ($row_msg_cont = $result_msg_cont->fetch())
    {
        $data[] = $row_msg_cont['assunto'];
    }


    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
  ............
  .............
  <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto">
  </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#assunto").autocomplete({
                source: 'retornaCliente.php' 
            });
        });

    </script>
    ...............
    ...............
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="t" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label>Cliente:</label>
    <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="minLength: 2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#assunto" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "retornaCliente.php",
                    data: { query: request.term},
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $("#myModalErro").modal('show');                       
                    },
                  dataType: 'json'
                });
            }
        });   
    });        

</script>

<div v id="myModalErro" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Erro </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**retornaCliente.php**

```
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="USUARIO";  
$password="SENHA";  
$db = "Nome_DB"; 

    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die();

    }

$assunto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'query', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT region FROM tbl_regiones WHERE region LIKE ? group by region ORDER BY region ASC');
$query->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

while ($results = $query->fetch())
{
    $data[] = $results['region'];
}

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT contador FROM tbl_region WHERE region LIKE ? ORDER BY region ASC LIMIT 7');
$query->execute(array("%$assunto%"));

while ($results = $query->fetch())
{
    $data[] = $results['contador'];
}


echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @Bacco, aproveitado na integra :)

Comment: @Bacco, ainda estou contemplando a ideia de colocar tudo em um array só.